# Read a single array and display as list in ionic app

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

In the Ionic app, I have an array as below.

The below is from console.log(this.itemlist);

```
0: Array(4)
0: "Item1"
1: "Item2"
2: "Item3"
3: "Item4"
length: 4
```

The problem is I am not able to display individual records as a single item in a list view in my ionic app.

My item.html looks like below:

```
<ion-item no-lines text-wrap class="item" *ngFor="let item of itemlist" >
<p>{{item}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

My item.ts looks like below:

```
if(localStorage.length > 0){
    var localStorageArray = new Array();
    for (i=0;i<localStorage.length;++i){
        localStorageArray[i] = localStorage.key(i)+localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    }
    var sortedArray = localStorageArray.sort();
}
this.itemlist.push(sortedArray);
console.log(this.itemlist);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `this.itemlist` has the wrong structure.. change your *ngFor to this `*ngFor="let item of itemlist[0]"`

When you push a value into an array, it is inserted as a new item in the array.. in your case the entire `sortedArray` is becoming the 0th element in your `itemlist`

Another solution would be to spread your array inside itemlist instead of using .push, like this

```
this.itemlist = [...sortedArray]
```